# Ideas for building a virtual conference

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to build a virtual conference framework which provides functionality for holding virtual summits/conferences.

Some of the core features:

- graphical representation of conference room hall (perhaps different genres?)
- Ability to invite people to summit/conference, register, unregister.
- Video podcasts/broadcasts.
- PPT and other presentation formats.

Other worthwhile ideas to add? Considering a Java EE/Java based platform - this decision purely based on my expertise. Are there any reference implementations/templates that I could use to start from instead of reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you look at the GoToMyPC offerings, GoToWebinar, GoToMeeting etc for features to implement.  Also take a look at Code Camp Server for an idea regarding the scheduling and so on of such events.